# invalid UTF8 string when i use QJsonDocument::fromJson

Tags: json, qt, utf-8, rhel, rhel5

In the latest version of Ubuntu, code by qt creator. Qt version is qt 5.41. When I use `QJsonDocument :: fromJson` create json objects, json object is created successfully. Code is as follows:

```
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    QString str = "{\"chinese\":\"china 中国\"}";
    QJsonDocument json;
    QJsonParseError error;
    json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(str.toUtf8(),&error);

    qDebug()<<json.toJson();
    //In Rhel5 Result:NULL

    qDebug()<<error.errorString();
     //In Rhel5 Result:invalid UTF8 string"

    str = "{\"english\":\"china english\"}";
    json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(str.toUtf8(),&error);

    qDebug()<<json.toJson();
   //In Rhel5 Result successful : 
  //    {
  //    "english": "china english"
  //     }

   qDebug()<<error.errorString();//In Rhel5 Result:no error occurred""
 return 0;
}
```

However, when the exact same code to run on `rhel5`, I got a description of the error: invalid UTF8 string. On `rhel5`, compiled `qt5` library functions, so you can execute programs on qt5 rhel5.

When json string is in English, `rhel5` run properly, correct json string.

In addition, `rhel5` support utf-8 encoded.

Comment: Try to output somewhere your str before parsing. Some compilers doesn't support sources in utf8.

Comment: it is not work.i can use qDebug().Chinese can be output。@SaZ

Comment: `qDebug` is not good solution, because console may not support unicode. Try to do an output to file. Be sure, that ICU is used as string backend by Qt in your target platform.

Comment: SaZ, that is my test code:

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    QByteArray str = "{\"chinese\":\"广东\"}";
    qDebug()<<str;
    QFile file("resutl.txt");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out<<str;
    file.close();
 return 0
 }@SaZ

Comment: In rhel 5,i can get the result.txt. 
 It can display Chinese. I use notepad ++ View result.txt.
 it is encode in UTF-8 without BOM .@SaZ,it is right?